# Restrict a imageview in a layout while dragging in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am implementing drag and drop in `android 4.1`. But i want to restrict the dragged view in a layout. Is there any method present in `android 4.1` to implement this or we have to use  motion event for this ?

Please help in solving this.

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict the dragged view in a layout"?

Comment: the view can't be dragged from a certain region or can be dragged inside that view only.